# Calculating slope between two points

Tags: qgis, gdal, dem, slope

I want to know slope value between two point with lat and long coordinates. I can also get DEM values at lat long location for both points. What should I do next in order to calculate slope?

Comment: Well I want to get slope in degrees but between two points that are really close to each other. I know thah I can calculate slope based on input DEM raster and the output will be slope raster but in this case I want just one value- a slope between two close points.Is this even possible?

Comment: slope in % = elevation-delta / distance

Comment: What is the best way to calculate distance from lat-long if I need slope as output?

Comment: Not work in lat-long in the first place.

Comment: But if my area of interest is very large, for example USA how I decide what projection/s should I use?